# Retrieve a single columnSQLl from database

Tags: sql, database

Which code do I need to retrieve a single value `i` from a column from table in SQL?

```
user_comment_count
```

This is column name in table

table is :

```
zmar_hreviews_list_total
```

This is code I use with error:

```
<?php
$insert1 ="/// ";
$string = "ars <pre>{$insert1}</pre>";
$query = 'SELECT user_comment_count FROM zmar_hreviews_list_total WHERE contentid = '.$item->getId();
$db->setQuery( $query );
$result = $db->loadResult();   
if($result) {
    $result = str_replace('*','',$result);
    print_r($insert1); print_r($result);
}
?>
```

Comment: I will be blunt. Your question is either missing information that makes this problem unique, or it is answerable with an easy Google search.

Comment: SandPiper maybe i must be more clearly ;  this is code i use with error : <?php $insert1 ="/// "; $string = "ars <pre>{$insert1}</pre>"; $query = 'SELECT user_comment_count FROM zmar_hreviews_list_total WHERE contentid = '.$item->getId(); $db->setQuery( $query ); $result = $db->loadResult(); if($result) { $result = str_replace('*','',$result); print_r($insert1); print_r($result); } ?>

Comment: ok i get warning from component creator , they uses the core Joomla #__content.hits table column. , so forget code above in question , how can i retrieve , this code give also error : $query = 'SELECT hits  FROM zmar__content WHERE contentid = '.$item->getId();
$db->setQuery( $query );
$result = $db->loadResult();   
if($result) {
    $result = str_replace('*','',$result);

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
 select user_comment_count from zmar_hreviews_list_total
```

Comment: thanks Gusti Arya but i will all code because this is not working :   <?php
   $insert1 ="/// "; 
            $string = "års <pre>{$insert1}</pre>";
   $query = 'SELECT user_comment_count FROM zmar_hreviews_list_total WHERE contentid = '.$item->getId();
   $db->setQuery( $query );
   $result = $db->loadResult();
   if($result) {
   $result = str_replace('*','',$result);
   print_r($insert1);
   print_r($result);
   }
?>